# CMS Question for a shopping cart site

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, portal

Greetings, i was ordered to build a portal where a user gets rewarded with points by buying to our company, and then those points can be redeemed by ordering some products according to those points.

I need to know if there is any *e-Commerce* **CMS** that may work that way.

the whole points assignation will be managed on another site, and transferred via DB to this.

Do you guys have any suggestions? I looked over **OsCommerce** and *Joomla's* **VirtueMart**, but I don't think they are what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [Magneto](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)
- [Cube Cart](http://www.cubecart.com/site/home/)
- [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/)
- [Presta Cart](http://www.prestashop.com/)

Not too sure about the points functionality being built in but there's probably a 3rd party module floating around which will do what you need it to.

HTH